# Microsoft Edge: unable to save cookies

Tags: cookies, microsoft-edge

So, recently I moved to a new PC. Very soon I discovered very unpleasant thing: my default browser, MS Edge, can't remember any cookie on any website. You log in to, let say, GMail, do all the staff to read/write emails, then close the tab. One second later you decide to go back to gmail again and woops! You have to login again. Even if you have logged in, open the same website in the next tab and no cookies again, you have to re-authenticate again.

Indeed first idea was about wrong settings. However, I clearly see "Don't block cookies" at "Privacy & Security". (and if I switch to "Block all cookies", I don't have any auth working at all, as expected). Googling gave noting so far but dummy texts/videos about "Don't block cookies" combobox which I have in correct position already, both in UI and system registry.

My Microsoft Edge is v44.18362.1.0 (previous PC was on v.42 and it was working perfectly OK)

Any clue how to return MS Edge ability to save cookies? Maybe, it is about security settings or so?

Comment: Are you using Chromium Edge or EdgeHTML?

Comment: @Ramhound, it's EdgeHTML 18.18362

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Edge blocking cookies is quite frequent and has caused many headaches.
Its cause is still unknown, but may have something to do with profile corruption
of the user account when Windows is installing a major upgrade.

Here is a list of some solutions that worked for some people:

- Create a new administrator account
- Disabling family safety (if enabled)
- Repairing the Microsoft Edge app:

  - Go to *Settings > Apps > Apps & features*
  - In the Search box, enter *Edge*
  - Click on Edge and then on *Advanced options*
  - Click the Repair button and follow the prompts
  - Close Settings
  - Reboot
  - If no success, in *Advanced options* as above click the Reset button
  - Follow the prompts
  - Close Settings
  - Reboot
- Doing a Windows refresh (action of last resort, after saving your data).
  Before doing this step, you should seriously consider moving on to Chrome or Firefox.

Please note that Microsoft is currently preparing a replacement to Edge that is
based on the Chromium/Chrome browser. Therefore there is no point in investing
much work on the Edge product which will be replaced in the near future.

Comment: Still nothing. This is the best way to bury Edge. I wonder, did MS has hired a traitor?

Comment: Edge is being replaced soon with Chrome, then the problem is solved.